# Supervising items of maxium value with a defined amount of supervisors using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I have this problem that I want to solve. I have n items, each with a value v placed in a line. Then I have k supervising items, a supervising item on position x can supervise items x-1, x, x+1. What I want to calculate is the maximum value that that k supervisors can oversee using dynamic programming.

eg.
n = {1,2,3,4}
v = {7,10,5,8}
which means that total value for a supervisor on position 1 -> 17 (n = 1 & 2 can be covered).
pos. 2 -> 22 (n = 1,2,3 can be covered).
pos. 3 -> 23 (n = 2,3,4 can be covered).
pos 4 -> 19 (n = 3,4 can be covered).

So how to calculate the maximum value that a given number of supervisors can cover?
In this example with 1 supervisor we get a maximum value 23, with 2 we get 36 (pick 1 & 4)
after that we can't do better since all items are covered.

I have tried utilizing the knapsack problem but then I get stuck with how to solve overlapping of coverage.
I have also tried to use the weighted interval scheduling problem but it only works for calculating the total max value possible not the max value for k intervals.

I very grateful for any tips I could get with how to solve this problem with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1 <= i <= n and 0 <= j <= k define DP[i][j] as maximum value of supervised items among these with indices in {1..i} when *j* supervisors can be set. Then DP[i + 1][j + 1] = max(A, B, C) where

A = DP[i][j + 1] // this covers all cases when the last supervisor is at *i-1* or eariler

B = DP[i-2][j] + val(i - 1) + val(i) + val(i + 1) // place supervisor at *i*

C = DP[i - 1][j] + val(i) + val(i + 1) // place supervisor at *i+1*

that gives O(n*k)